# Finding gaps between date ranges spanning records

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a query where I can find any gap in the date ranges for a given `ID` when passing in two dates.

**EDIT: I need to know if a whole gap or part of a gap exists in my date range.**

I have data in this format:

```
Example 1:

| ID | START_DATE | END_DATE   |
|----|------------|------------|
| 1  | 01/01/2019 | 30/09/2019 |
| 1  | 01/03/2020 | (null)     |

Example 2:

| ID | START_DATE | END_DATE   |
|----|------------|------------|
| 2  | 01/01/2019 | 30/09/2019 |
| 2  | 01/10/2019 | 01/12/2019 |
| 2  | 02/12/2019 | (null)     |
```

NB. A null end date essentially means "still active up to current day".

E.g. `Example 1` has a gap of 152 days between 30/09/2019 and 01/03/2020. If I queried in the range of `05/05/2019 - 01/09/2019` there's no gap in that range. Whereas if I'm looking at the date range `05/05/2019 - 02/10/2019` there's a single day gap in that range.

For what it's worth, I don't actually care how many days gap, just whether there is one or not.

I've tried doing something like this but it doesn't work when my date falls into a gap:

```sql
SELECT SUM(START_DATE - PREV_END - 1)
FROM
   (
   SELECT ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, LAG(END_DATE) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE) AS PREV_END_DATE
   FROM TBL
   WHERE ID = X_ID
   )
WHERE START_DATE >= Y_FIRST_DATE
AND START_DATE <= Z_SECOND_DATE;
```

`X_ID`, `Y_FIRST_DATE`, and `Z_SECOND_DATE` are just any different ID or date range I might want to pass in.

How could I go about this?

Comment: Please clarify the input data. Your table has a list of intervals. There may be gaps between these intervals. Parameters are: `ID` and `some given interval`. You want to figure out if `some given interval` intersects with any of the gaps for the given `ID`. Right? Please provide few more good examples with sample data and **your expected outcome** for them. So far, there is only one example. What result do you expect for ID=2?

Comment: Side note. It is highly recommended to store intervals as [closed; open). It makes a lot of things simpler. In the same way, as most programming languages have array indexes 0-based, rather than 1-based.

Comment: At a glance, I'd do it like this: at first convert your list of intervals to a list of gaps (on the fly, using `LEAD`), then for each gap check if it intersects with the `given interval` and count the number of intersections. Two intervals `[a1; a2)` and `[b1; b2)` intersect if `b1<a2 and b2>a1`.

Comment: I've given two examples of data and below that I've described what my expected outcome is, and my attempt which also shows my intended output (although, as I said, I don't especially mind the format of the output I just want a boolean of some variety). I'm not sure what your side note means, but I can't change how this data is stored (apart from perhaps wrapping in a view which converts it into some other format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option to determine the days might be by use `SELECT .. FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <=` syntax through `EXIST`ence of gaps by `INTERSECT`ing two sets, one finds all dates between extremum parameters while the other finds all the dates fitting within the dates inserted into table as bounds :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
       SUM( 1 + LEAST(Z_SECOND_DATE,NVL(END_DATE,TRUNC(SYSDATE))) 
         - GREATEST(Y_FIRST_DATE,START_DATE) ) = Z_SECOND_DATE - Y_FIRST_DATE + 1 THEN
           'NO Gap'
       ELSE
           'Gap Exists'  
       END "gap?"
  FROM TBL t
 WHERE ID = X_ID
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT Y_FIRST_DATE + LEVEL - 1
                  FROM dual
               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= Z_SECOND_DATE - Y_FIRST_DATE + 1 
               INTERSECT
                SELECT t.START_DATE + LEVEL - 1
                  FROM dual
               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= NVL(t.END_DATE,TRUNC(SYSDATE))- t.START_DATE + 1
               )
```

`START_DATE` values are assumed to be non-null based on the sample data.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f4d12dbcd2222262bc251f436219b446)</kbd>

Comment: Your assumption is correct: `start_date` can never be null. This seems to be doing the trick for the sample data I provided. Before marking as the answer I'm going to do some more testing with more data and see how it goes.

Comment: Okay so this doesn't quite work either when there's multiple records: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a19d7d98b67759fc2cf3e35e163e9f52

Comment: well, you're right just added `SUM()` aggregation after testing with those rows @WSC

Comment: Ah yes, that did the trick. I feel a bit stupid now for not thinking about that. I'm going to do some more testing just to verify but think this does the job the best.

Comment: No, not important, this way I'm also able to fix @WSC .

Answer (score 1):

This is another variation the islands-and-gaps problem that pops up a lot here.  I think this fits with Oracle's pattern matching functionality.  Take this example:

```sql
WITH tbl AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS ID, to_date('01/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS START_DATE, to_date('30/09/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS END_DATE FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS ID, to_date('01/03/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS START_DATE, NULL AS END_DATE FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS ID, to_date('01/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS START_DATE, to_date('30/09/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS END_DATE FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS ID, to_date('01/10/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS START_DATE, to_date('01/12/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS END_DATE FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS ID, to_date('02/12/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS START_DATE, NULL AS END_DATE FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
FROM tbl
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(ORDER BY ID, start_date
                MEASURES b.id AS ID,
                         a.end_date+1 AS GAP_START,
                         b.start_date-1 AS GAP_END
                PATTERN (A B+)
                DEFINE B AS start_date > PREV(end_date)+1 AND ID = PREV(ID))L;
```

I know it looks long, but most of it is creating the WITH clause.  The pattern matching allows you to define what a gap is and pull the information accordingly.  Notice that in order to have a gap, your start date must be greater than the previous end date + 1 grouped by the ID column.

To enhance this to answer your updated/edited question, just add this line of code to the end:

```sql
WHERE GREATEST(gap_start, TO_DATE('15/09/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY' /*Y_FIRST_DATE*/)) <= LEAST(gap_end, to_date('15/10/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')/*Z_SECOND_DATE*/)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what this is doing and isn't valid SQL in Oracle (11g).

Comment: @WSC MATCH_RECOGNIZE is a 12c feature.  The SQL is valid though.

Comment: Ah right, that'll be it then. Unfortunately we're still on 11g.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the date range you are passing, into dates and then compare it with a date range in your table as follows:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN T.ID IS NULL THEN 1 END) > 0 
         THEN 'THERE IS GAP'
         ELSE 'THERE IS NO GAP'
    END AS RESULT_
FROM ( SELECT P_IN_FROM_DATE + LEVEL - 1 AS CUST_DATES
         FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= P_IN_TO_DATE - P_IN_FROM_DATE + 1
    ) CUST_TBL
    LEFT JOIN TBL T 
    ON CUST_TBL.CUST_DATES BETWEEN T.START_DATE AND T.END_DATE
       OR ( CUST_TBL.CUST_DATES >= T.START_DATE AND T.END_DATE IS NULL )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest finding the maximum end date *before* the current record -- based on the start date.

That would be:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(end_date) over (order by start_date
                                 rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                ) as max_prev_end_date
      from tbl t
      where start_date <= :input_end_date and
            end_date >= :input_start_date
     ) t
where max_prev_end_date < start_date;
```

Comment: There's an additional `and` here: `end_date >= :input_start_date and` is there another predicate that's meant to follow or just copy/paste typo?

Comment: In my first example, if I pass in `start date 02/10/2019` and `end date 01/03/2020` this returns null because my start date, `02/10/2019`, falls into a gap (i.e. after end date `30/09/2019` but before `01/03/2020` but I'd like to be able to know if a whole gap or part of a gap exists in my date range.

Comment: @WSC . . . No, that is not a typo, but thank you for asking.  You might need `<` rather than `<` to capture a gap on the first day.  It is not clear if that really counts as a gap if the gap is before your time range.

Comment: Hm... If it's not a mistake then there's a missing predicate? That SQL isn't valid with the trailling `and`. I'll have a play around a bit more.